# Spring SOAP webservice - measure parallel connections?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap

Is it possible to measure the number of active parallel webservice connections? Maybe by a spring `Event`?

```
@Component
@WebService
public class Myervice {
    @WebMethod
    public void test() {
           //measure parallel connections?
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to record this or just monitor this?

Comment: At first just monitor it. Then I could of course lateron implement a logging.